# Iterated expectation of jointly normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

$X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are jointly normal, each with zero mean and strictly positive variance. Let $T = E[Z | Y]$, $U = E[T | X]$, and $V = E[U | Y]$. I'm trying to show that $T = V$ (which might *not* be true).

I have tried to apply the law of iterated expectation to solve this, but haven't had much success. For example, when I plug $T$ into $U$ I got $U = E[E[Z | Y] | X]$. Since the $X$ here is not a subset of $Y$, I can't reduce this to $E[Z|X]$ with the law of iterated expectation.

I'm pretty confused how I could show this, or maybe find a counterexample to prove it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For a jointly normal distribution

$$E[Z|Y] = E[Z] + \frac{\text{Cov}[Z,Y]}{\text{Var[Y]}}(Y-E[Y])$$

and this is applicable for any variable combination. [See also here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions).